# Change the column's datatype for a partitioned table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dacpac

My team has a database table that is partitioned running on SQL Server 2008 R2. In the table, there is a PK that is an `INT`. We're about to run out of INTs.

We plan on changing to `BIGINT`. We manage all of our data operations via DACPAC projects (Visual Studio's SQL project). One DACPAC for each database on our server. Thing is, we can't find an elegant way to change the PK column's datatype. We found a bunch of manual procedures that look useful, but we'd really like a script we can generate on the fly using DACPAC projects.

We're looking to automate this process, and have a simple one click script from the DACPAC that will update the DB in one fell swoop.

Might anyone know of an elegant solution?

Any help / suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the database have a substantial window of time where this table can be offline? If not I'd be highly sceptical that the generated script from a dacpac publish would be suitable.

Comment: I believe we are going to have to live with some downtime.  Good question.

Comment: If you're dead set on the DACPAC, it's easy enough: just make one that includes only a single post-deployment script that does the actual work. This is, of course, no more useful than just running a script file separately, but if your workflow requires the DACPAC, that's one way to do it. The DACPAC deployment process itself (comparing before and after) is almost certainly not sophisticated enough to do this operation automatically -- data migration is not its strong suit.

Comment: Have you made the required changes to your SSDT project and reviewed the script it creates for publish? I imagine it will create something that works. Just possibly something that won't perform well when used against large production tables.